# Formatting Time and Date in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Running `rails c`  this works:

```
2.2.3 :002 > Post.find(1).created_at.strftime("Posted on %B %d, %Y at %H:%M")
Post Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
=> "Posted on October 23, 2015 at 15:31"
```

But running `rails server` I get an error:

```
index.html.erb where line #28 raised:
Object must be a Date, DateTime or Time object. "Posted on October 26, 2015 at 11:44" given.
```

index.html.erb looks like:

```
<%- model_class = Post -%>
<table class="table table-striped">
<thead>      
<tr>
<th><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:created_at) %></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<% @posts.each_with_index do |post, index| %>
<tr> 
<td><%=l post.created_at.strftime("Posted on %B %d, %Y at %H:%M") %>
</td>
</td>
</tr>
<% end %>
</tbody>
```

Comment: I advice to have a lool at the [Rails Guide about how to format dates/times](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#adding-date-time-formats)

Comment: Just as a FYI, your .erb doesn't contain valid HTML. You have two `</td>` terminating a cell, and are missing the terminating `</table>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the problem is just a stray `l` at the beginning of your code.

This should work:

```
<%= post.created_at.strftime("Posted on %B %d, %Y at %H:%M") %>
```

Better yet would be to move this time formatting to a model and call that on post. And move "Posted on" outside the method. So:

```
<td> Posted on <%= post.formatted_created_on %> </td>
```

Comment: I'd have to disagree with the `formatted_created_on` method, formatting and display issues really aren't the model's concern. A *view* helper for consistently formatting dates OTOH...

Comment: Oh, yeah true. Wasn't thinking there.